# DOM Event doesn't working without arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It is a React code to delete an item in the list when double click it.

```
import React from 'react';

const IterationSample = () => {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, text: 'A' },
    { id: 2, text: 'B' },
    { id: 3, text: 'C' },
    { id: 4, text: 'D' }
  ]);

  const onRemove = id => {
    const nextNames = names.filter(name => name.id !== id);
    setNames(nextNames);
  };

  const nameList = names.map(name => {
    return (
    <li key={name.id} onDoubleClick={() => onRemove(name.id)}>
      {name.text}
    </li>
    )
  });

  return (
      <ul>{nameList}</ul>
  );
};

export default IterationSample;
```

Question: In this part,

```
const nameList = names.map(name => {
    return (
    <li key={name.id} onDoubleClick={() => onRemove(name.id)}>
      {name.text}
    </li>
    )
  });
```

If I change the code like this, Why it doesn't work?

```
const nameList = names.map(name => {
    return (
    <li key={name.id} onDoubleClick={onRemove(name.id)}>
      {name.text}
    </li>
    )
  });
```

The list is not rendered and no error message is displayed in console.

Comment: In the second case the function directly executes without depending on the double click event.Hence you need to pass a function definition instead of calling it directly

Comment: `onDoubleClick` expecting a function to be passed, but in second case you are calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case you have defined a function by using the => arrow fucntion

But In second case you have called the function

So update your code with following one for second case

```
const nameList = names.map(name => {
return (
<li key={name.id} onDoubleClick={this.onRemove.bind(null,name.id)}>
  {name.text}
</li>
)
```

});

Answer (score 1):

`onDoubleClick={onRemove(name.id)}` is not the React way of assigning a function to event, the first way 
i.e.,
`onDoubleClick={() => onRemove(name.id)}` works because on double click is assigned a function that invokes your `onRemove(name.id)` but in the other case you are invoking function directly, if you are confused where you are invoking let me clear the air, anything inside `{javascript code}` is evaluated before so when you write
`{onRemove(name.id)}` the function is evaluated meaning the function is invoked.
on the other hand when you write `{()=> onRemove(name.id)}` the evaluated function is resulting a new function that invokes other function. Hope I explained it clearly. For a better understanding [react way of passing functions as props](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders), the link is from official docs.

Answer (score 1):

React implements something called Synthetic Events to wrap DOM events for cross-browser compatibility. This is the reason the event handler needs a reference to the function and not the function call itself Check out this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for in-depth details.